# Solved by myself. Pointers but i don't know why

Tags: c++, class

This is something I don't understand. Got 2 classes: ClassA and ClassB.
When i'm creating classB by parameter constructor with pointer to ClassA..this object is **deleted**(destructor runs his funcion)
. (ALREADY SOLVED, but i don't know why?)
(Is everthing ok with this? Just want to write it without logic mistakes)
I solved it by changing place of " * ". From

```
    pointerB = new ClassB(*this);
to
    pointerB = new ClassB(this);

and
ClassB::ClassB(ClassA pointer)
to
ClassB::ClassB(ClassA *pointer)
```

OLD CODE:

```
main.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "ClassA.h"
#include "ClassB.h"

    int main()
    {
        //pointer for object ClassA
        ClassA *A;
        //New Object
        A = new ClassA();



        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

ClassA.cpp

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "ClassA.h"


    ClassA::ClassA()
    {
        std::cout << "CLASS A OBJECT CREATED" << std::endl;
        //Creation of B
        pointerB = new ClassB();
        pointerB = new ClassB(*this);
    }


    ClassA::~ClassA()
    {
        std::cout << "CLASS A OBJECT DELETED" << std::endl;
    }

ClassA.h

    #pragma once
    #include <iostream>
    #include "ClassB.h"
    extern class ClassB;
    class ClassA
    {
        ClassB *pointerB;
    public:
        ClassA();
        ~ClassA();
    };
ClassB.cpp

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "ClassB.h"


    ClassB::ClassB()
    {
        std::cout << "CLASS B OBJECT CREATED by constructor" << std::endl;

    }
    ClassB::ClassB(ClassA pointer) {
        std::cout << "CLASS B OBJECT CREATED with pointer" << std::endl;
    }

    ClassB::~ClassB()
    {
        std::cout << "CLASS B OBJECT DELETED" << std::endl;
    }
ClassB.h

    #pragma once
    #include <iostream>
    #include "ClassA.h"
    extern class ClassA;
    class ClassB
    {
        ClassA * pointerA;

    public:
        ClassB();
        ClassB(ClassA *pointer);
        ~ClassB();
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the declaration `ClassB::ClassB(ClassA pointer)`, the parameter of the constructor is an object of type `ClassA` *not* a pointer to an object of type `ClassA`. Therefore you had to dereference your `this` pointer in your old code. In the call `pointerB = new ClassB(*this);` the constructor of `ClassB` does *not* receive the instance pointed to by `this`, but a *copy* of that instance. That *copy* will be deleted after that call returns. This is why you see the destructor of `ClassA` being called. If you output the `this` pointer (e.g. as hexadecimal integer) in both constructor and destructor, you would see that there is a different `this` pointer in the constructor and in the destructor. Or better: use a debugger and you will see this. You could also declare a copy constructor for `ClassA`, then you would see that it is called in `pointerB = new ClassB(*this);`.

Now if you want the very instance pointed to by `this` to be passed to the constructor of `ClassB`, you can do so by declaring it as pointer as you did in your solution, or you could pass it as reference. E.g. you declare the constructor of `ClassB` as

```
 ClassB::ClassB(ClassA& aClassA) {}
```

Then you can call `pointerB = new ClassB(*this);` without the `ClassA` object being copied.

Some little remarks on your code:

- try to avoid unnecessary dependencies in header files. You don't need to `#include <iostream>` in `ClassA.h`, because nothing in `ClassA.h` depends on it. Only the code in `ClassA.cpp` depends on `<iostream>`. So, you should include that there.
- a forward declaration is a good thing and helps to avoid unnecessary includes. But the syntax is just `class ClassB;` (without "`extern`"). Then you don't need to `#include "ClassB.h"` in `ClassA.h`.
- if something is not a pointer, you should not call it `pointer`. This is probably the source of all the mistakes.

Comment: If you find a solution yourself, then it is good practice to post that solution. Thus you can share what you have learned and others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Before your change a copy of ClassA object was passed to ClassB constructor. And after the constructor finished, the copy was destroyed. That's why you saw the print from the destructor.

By default, the compiler will create the copy constructor that blindly copies all data to the new place in memory implicitly. If you want to see the call of copy constructor you should define your own constructor that accepts the const reference of the same type `ClassA(const ClassA&)`.

After your change an address of already created object is passed hence no copy is created.

I would not say that your code is OK. You broke the rule of three, because you use your own destructor and failed to create the copy constructor and assignment operator. see  - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three. Also the object created with "new" were not deleted properly.